# Check row length if greater then 0 then print data and while printing add for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam trying to print data base value and the radio buttons in to a div but my problem is first if there are no rows in the table i need to show that there are no rows and the second probllem i want to add `for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)` for condition as am using radio buttons that are dynamically generated i need to add `i` means number to each fetch.

```
   string xxx= SessionManager.xxxxxxxx;
   string htmlStr = "";
   using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
   {
       string oString = "Select * from xxxxx WHERE xxxx=@xxxx and xxxx=@xxxx ";
       MySqlCommand oCmd = new MySqlCommand(oString, myConnection);

       oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxx", "0");    
       oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxx", "0");          
       myConnection.Open();
       using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (oReader.Read())
           {
              string Name = oReader["xxxx"].ToString();
              // string Pass = oReader["xxxx"].ToString();
              htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + Name + "</td><td><input type='radio' name='Present' value='Present'></td><td><input type='radio' name='Absent' value='Absent'></td><td><input type='radio' name='Leave' value='Leave'></td></tr>";                             
           }

           myConnection.Close();
      }               
   }

   STUDENT_LIST.InnerHtml = htmlStr;
```

Comment: Why you are adding the controls like this? you can use `ASP.NET Repeater` control to display data with any custom template. Or if you just want to display records in tabular format use `Gridview` control.

Comment: @RahulSingh is there any threat if i do like this if yes i would be thank full if u suggest me that repeater one

Comment: See for instance [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) (scroll down to the examples)

Comment: @HansKesting is there a problem if i create like this what i have done is there any chances of failure

Comment: @Shaik - with the built-in controls you have better separation of markup and code. This might be easier to work with when the markup gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

MySqlDataReader has a readonly property called as "HasRows". The usage of it is;

```
if(oReader.HasRows)
{
  // Perform operation
}
else
  // Some other operation
```

The link for detailed list of members and methods of MySqlDataReader is [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader_members.html)

UPDATE:

If you are looking for an example for the usage of MySqlDataAdapter, I would suggest you to go through the DataSet & MySqlDataAdapter section of [this link](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it would be help full if u suggest me the row count also the above is perfect

Comment: According to the mentioned link, there are three distinct count,
1. FieldCount; returns the number of columns. Usage oReader.FieldCount
2. RecordCount: returns the number of rows. Usage oReader.RecordCount
3. ResultCount: returns the number of retrieved results. Usage: oReader.ResultCount.

PS: To be honest, I have never used MySql Connection with C#.NET. SqlDataReader has all these properties. Hence I assume that they are also available in the extensions as well. :)

Hope this comment helps..

Comment: In your case this answer strictly right. But if you will use SqlDataAdapter with DataSet, you may know exact rows count.

Comment: @Khazratbek if u suggest an example i would be thank full to you

Comment: @Shaik, since you are using the DataReader and while(oReader.Read()) as your data retrieval option, why not use a increment logic. Have a variable declared before the loop and increment this variable for each read. By using this, you don't have to use an extra loop just to assign the row numbers.

Comment: @Shaik SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(your_sql_command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

Comment: @KrishnaKumarN if you saw in his question, he try to execute some code until some value (in his case rows count minus one), but if he just will use increment, he can't know the value before he will finish, so he can't break in some value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from your_table", con);

try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    int num = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
       //Do something here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I wrote in comment, but I've decided to give you a full version what you exactly need. Hope it helps